# How to set parameters for archiving knowledge article in Salesforce Flow

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, knowledge, screen-flow, articles

I am trying to archive a published Knowledge Article using Salesforce flow. I tried using the standard Knowledge Action 'Archive online knowledge articles' for this purpose. However, when I try to use it, it prompts me to provide a list of Article Version Ids. When I try passing a list, it throws an error: **'The data type of the resource you entered isn't compatible.'**
Can anyone please explain what exact data needs to be passed as a parameter? Does the list have to be of some specific object or type?

[image]

I face the same issue when trying to Publish a Knowledge article using the standard Knowledge action in flow. I am not sure what exact data needs to be passed for the 'Article Version ID List'.

I tried with both KnowledgeFAQ_kav and KnowledgeArticleVersion and neither seems to work:
[image]

It is taking only Record (Single) Variables and when I am trying to use any of the ones I created, it shows a list of all the related lookup fields except the ID:
[image]

No matter what I choose, I keep seeing endless options of lookup fields and none of the options seem to work.

Comment: are you using the sobjectType that ends in `__kav` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried using both KnowledgeFAQ__kav and KnowledgeArticleVersion and neither seems to work. I have edited the post to include screenshots for it as well.

Comment: @it-nish what is the data type of the draftArticleIdList variable that you're passing in the first screenshot?

Comment: It is KnowledgeFAQ__kav

Comment: were you able to find the solution for this ?

Comment: The only solution I found was that I have to use a for loop explicitly. If I use a for loop and store the ids in a collection, then I can use that collection in this action. However, if I try to use Get Records and store the values in a collection it doesn't work. For some reason, an extra step of for loop is needed

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me: use a For Loop explicitly. If I use a for loop and store the ids in a collection, then I can use that collection in this Knowledge flow action. However, if I try to use Get Records and store the values in a collection it doesn't work. For some reason, an extra step of for loop is needed.